# Unable to update "dueAt" or "dueOn" fields on Tasks using Asana API for Java

Tags: java, datetime, asana-api

Im trying to create a task with "dueAt" and "dueOn" fields but Im unable to fill these fields.

I have created the task "copyTask" by Asana website and Im able to fill due dates. But if I try to create another task using Asana API for Java and give it any value to "dueAt" or "dueOn" fields, they aren't filled with anything.

I have used this:

```
      newTask = asanaClient.tasks.createInWorkspace(workspaceId)
                            .data("name", "MyProofTask")
                            .data("notes", "MyDescriptionTask")
                            .data("projects", Arrays.asList(newProject.id))
                            .data("dueAt", (copyTask.dueAt != null) ? new com.google.api.client.util.DateTime (copyTask.dueAt.getValue()) : null)
                            .data("dueOn", (copyTask.dueOn != null ? new com.google.api.client.util.DateTime (copyTask.dueOn.getValue()) : null))
                            .execute();
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `"due_at"` and `"due_on"`.

```
  newTask = asanaClient.tasks.createInWorkspace(workspaceId)
                        .data("name", "MyProofTask")
                        .data("notes", "MyDescriptionTask")
                        .data("projects", Arrays.asList(newProject.id))
                        .data("due_at", (copyTask.dueAt != null) ? new com.google.api.client.util.DateTime (copyTask.dueAt.getValue()) : null)
                        .data("due_on", (copyTask.dueOn != null ? new com.google.api.client.util.DateTime (copyTask.dueOn.getValue()) : null))
                        .execute();
```